# Imgur error 403 but only while using cloud hosted copy

Tags: python, imgur

so i made a python program that at some point posts an image to imgur, and it completely works on my local pc.
but when i tried putting it on a cloud hosting service (Digital Ocean) and running it via there, it just returns a 403 saying "Imgur is temporarily over capacity. Please try again later."

**the code:**

```
            rand = random.randint(1, requests.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species").json()["count"])
            poke = requests.get(f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{rand}").json()

            pokeimage = poke["sprites"]["other"]["official-artwork"]["front_default"]
            og_pokeimage = pokeimage

            file = None
            if hard != None:

                trueimage = requests.get(pokeimage).content

                # Open image and make into Numpy array
                na = np.array(Image.open(io.BytesIO(trueimage)))

                # Make every pixel, of every row of every column black in RGB channels, i.e. channel 0, 1, 2
                na[:, :, :3] = 0

                # Make Boolean True/False mask of all alphas > 200
                mask = na[:,:,3] > 200

                # Set alpha channel to 255 wherever mask is True, and 0 elsewhere
                na[:, :, 3] = mask * 255

                # Convert back from Numpy array to PIL Image
                pokepil = Image.fromarray(na)

                image_buffer = io.BytesIO()
                pokepil.save(image_buffer, format="PNG")
                encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_buffer.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")

                # Upload the Base64-encoded image to Imgur
                imgur_response = requests.post(
                    "https://api.imgur.com/3/image",
                    headers={"Authorization": f"Client-ID {self.imgclient}"},
                    data={"image": encoded_image}
                )
                imgur_data = imgur_response.json()
                await ctx.channel.send(imgur_data)

                # Retrieve the Imgur URL of the uploaded image
                pokeimage=imgur_data["data"]["link"]
```

I hope someone knows how to fix it!